# Combine.perKey nor GroupByKey behave incorrectly for late data

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My simplified scenario is that I want to count how many A and B events I am receiving each minute. I also need to support late data.

Let's assume I am receiving 2 A and 2 B events in the same window (00:00:00-00:00:001)
So the expected result is 2 A events and 2 B events
Then I receive 2 late B events for the same (00:00:00-00:00:001) window
I would expect that in the final pane I will get 2 A events and 4 B events

But actually I am getting some accumulated results from previous panes 
This is the [Gist with the sample code](https://gist.github.com/pbartoszek/795452a5015e60dcf8c2112ff941250e) that shows my problem

Below I outlined the actual and expected result.

```
Actual panes fired(accumulation mode):
    ./00:00-00:01-pane-0-on_time-first
     KV{A, 2}
     KV{B, 2}
     ./00:00-00:01-pane-1-late
     KV{A, 2}
     KV{B, 2}
     KV{B, 3}
     ./00:00-00:01-pane-2-late
     KV{A, 2}
     KV{B, 2}
     KV{B, 3}
     KV{B, 4}

Actual panes fired(discarding mode):
    ./00:00-00:01-pane-0-on_time-first
     KV{A, 2}
     KV{B, 2}
     ./00:00-00:01-pane-1-late
     KV{B, 3}
     ./00:00-00:01-pane-2-late
     KV{B, 4}


The expected result
     ./00:00-00:01-pane-0-on_time-first
     KV{A, 2}
     KV{B, 2}
     ./00:00-00:01-pane-1-late
     KV{A, 2}
     KV{B, 3}
     ./00:00-00:01-pane-2-late
     KV{A, 2}
     KV{B, 4}
```

Comment: My expectation is that this is happening within `TextIO.Write`, rather than within the `GroupByKey/Combine`. The actual elements produced by the Combine should be those you see being written in discarding mode, assuming the Combine accumulates fired panes and the downstream discards fired panes. If the entire pipeline is in discarding mode and the combine produces `KV{B, 3}` or `KV{B, 4}`, that isn't correct.

Comment: If you reconfigure the windowing after your Combine (e.g. `Window.configure().discardingFiredPanes()`), what outputs are written?